# Python posix IPC - communication between process running as a different user

Tags: python, python-3.x, posix, ipc, root

I am trying to establish communication between two different processes on Linux using POSIX IPC. I am using python 3 with posix message queues based on this library  http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/ .

The problem is that I want to communicate between a server that is running as root and a client that is running with normal user permissions (separate python program).

If the client creates the message queue then it works, presumably because it allocates under a normal user and the process running under root has higher permissions. I however want the server to create the message queue as that can properly manage the closure of the message queue when the server terminates etc.

Is it possible for a root process to create an IPC message queue and allow processes running under a different user to write to the queue? If so how?

Or is there any alternative to POSIX IPC that could be used instead (eg. Sys V)?
I'm hoping to avoid using UNIX sockets as I don't want the additional overhead that uses.

-- Update on latest attempt --

I've read up on all the documentation I can find. The library readme says that they found it to work regardless of permissions, but that's not my experience.

The Linux programming interface (on which the library relies) states to use both mode and umask, but even if I use os.umask(000) followed by mode=666 within the message queue setup I still get permission denied from the client.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Linux domain sockets.

Access to filesystem-based ones can be managed with filesystem permissions. Domain sockets in abstract namespace can be secured by checking credentials (PID/UID) of connecting process, — see also: "SCM_RIGHTS".

Domain sockets are very fast, — they are used by Xorg, so kernel developers have optimized them well. They are also more portable than POSIX IPC (supported on Android). Stream-based mode might be a bit awkward to use for message-oriented IPC, so you should consider switching to datagram mode instead.

Comment: The reason I don't want to use sockets is because this will be used for handling incoming web requests which then need to be passed on to the end server. If using domain sockets then each web request would need to establish a connection to the socket, send the request and receive the response before freeing the socket and returning.

 
Whereas if I used a message queue it can just get the address of memory, add the message to the queue and then check for a response (if required).

Comment: @StewartWatkiss opening new sockets for each message is unnecessary. Writes on datagram sockets are atomic, so you can keep a single connected socket, shared between any number of producers/consumers. Or a pool of sockets.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to give sockets a go. If the queues had worked then they would have fit better into how I wanted the communication to work but I have tried numerous different ways to get permissions to work using both sysV and posix queues without any success. I will need to change the way my code queues the messages to change it to sockets, but it's probably better than waisting more time on the message queues.